# How to remove the trackback and pingback text on the bottom of my pages?

Tags: pages, customization

I am getting this text on bottom of all the new pages i create; 
"TRACKBACKS AND PINGBACKS
No trackback or pingback available for this article."

The checkbox for trackback/pings is NOT checked in the admin section for each page, but it still shows up on each page with comments. What is the easiest way to remove the trackback and pingback text?

Comment: Are you talking about the front end or the back end?

Answer (score 1):

You can uncheck  Settings >> Discussion >> “Allow link notifications from other blogs (pingbacks and trackbacks) to disable disable for future posts. However, to disable for exiting posts you need to run a SQL query on your database to turn the ping_status to OFF:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET ping_status='closed' WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post';
```

and

`UPDATE wp_posts SET ping_status='closed' WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'page';`

Comment: Sure. Can you mark the answer as useful please?

Comment: Same could be achieved by bulk quick-editing all pages and setting the setting to disabled pingbacks. That SQL would be better only in case of thousands of pages, limited server resources or multiple post types to be edited.